# How to maintain the contents in the text field after redircting to same page jsp.

Tags: java, jsp

Hi I have jsp page That is having some text fields,I will fill that text fields and I will submit that form to server side.If any error comes in the server side I will redirect to the same page with error message Now I want that text field to remain as it is but in my case it is clearing.How to make the text field as same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055308/retaining-the-submitted-jsp-form-data

Comment: I that link the answers are no accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The two options available to you are:

1. Don't reload the page. Instead submit the data via AJAX or validate it by javascript. That way you don't ever have to touch the data in the form. Make sure your javascript highlights the fields that have errors in some way.
2. The endpoint that you're POSTing your data to needs to be able to recognise that the data is invalid and include that data when returning the user to the same page. I'm not familiar with jsp, but generally you'd do that by including variables in your template for your form that could contain the data, and passing empty strings on the first load of the page. If the page is then shown to the user again after a failed form validation, pass back the POST data that you received in your form request.

Answer (score 0):

There are two option, you can dispatch the request/response to the same page instead of redirect,  but you need to add an attribute and recover it in the JSP, or you can add the attribute in the session , recover the value to de text field and remove it using (if you are using JSTL)